# How to implement OpenGL triple buffering of buffer objects to avoid stalls?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es2, frame-buffer

I'm trying to implement the triple buffering described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/OpenGLESApplicationDesign/OpenGLESApplicationDesign.html). The intent is to gain higher frame rate by avoiding waiting for `glBufferSubData()` to finish.

My understanding is that this is how to implement triple buffer:

```
- make 3 buffers with glGenBuffers()
Current frame:
  - bind to buffer3
  - draw last frame
  - bind to buffer1
  - glBufferSubData for all the vertices, 
  keep track of their texture/vertex count,blend function, etc
Next frame:
  - bind to buffer 1
  - draw last frame (bind texture, blend func, glDrawArrays)
  - and so on
```

There doesn't seem to be any performance gain between this and doing `glBufferSubData()` and then immediately calling `glDrawArrays()`.

Am I missing something or misunderstand how triple buffer should work?

Also is there a way to know when `glDrawArrays()` stalls due to `glBufferSubData()` still not being finished?

Comment: The driver will very probably multi-buffer behind the scenes for you if it can detect a consistent usage pattern.